# Disable Safari Tooltips from website

Tags: safari, webkit, tooltip

Is it possible to disable the tooltips that safari includes for sites from the website level?

I've been searching around and I see plenty of ways to disable it for your local machine, but if I have my own custom tooltip that I'm creating (I'm creating a table formatted one in a Sencha extjs project) can I tell Safari's webkit to not display it's tooltips?

If it's not possible to do from the website is there a way to control what text shows up in the Safari tooltip?

The goal is to have a tooltip with details on a record to display when hovering over a field in a table.

I already have a field containing the detailed information that I'm using for the Sencha project's tooltip. If I could tell Safari (or any other browser that forces it's own tooltips onto a site) to use that information it would also work.